# Counting the total number of types in a nested pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

`NumTypes<Args...>::value` is to give the total number of types in `Args...`, including all types in a nested packs (if any), e.g. if

```
using T = Group<int, bool, Wrap<char, Pack<char, long, Group<char, Object, short>, short>, double>, long>;
```

then `NumTypes<T, int, char>::value` will be 13 (we do not count the wrapper classes themselves).  The following code works correctly, but when I replace any of the types with `std::string` I get a flurry of `std::allocator` errors that never terminates (with GCC 4.8.1).  I suspect other types will generate the same error.  Why?  And how to fix the code to avoid this weird error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define show(variable) std::cout << #variable << " = " << variable << std::endl;

template <typename T>
struct IsPack {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Args>
struct IsPack<P<Args...>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename...> struct NumTypes;

template <typename T>
struct NumTypes<T> {
    static const int value = 1;
};

template <template <typename...> class P>
struct NumTypes<P<>> { static const int value = 0; };

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct NumTypes<P<First, Rest...>> {
    static const int value = IsPack<First>::value ?
        NumTypes<First>::value + NumTypes<P<Rest...>>::value :
        1 + NumTypes<P<Rest...>>::value;
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct NumTypes<First, Rest...> {
    static const int value = NumTypes<First>::value + NumTypes<Rest...>::value;
};

template <typename...> struct Pack;
template <typename...> struct Group;
template <typename...> struct Wrap;
struct Object {};

int main() {
    using A = Pack<int, Object, long>;
    show (NumTypes<A>::value)  // 3

    using B = Pack<int, bool, Pack<char, Object>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<B>::value)  // 5

    using C = Group<int, bool, Wrap<char, Pack<char, long, Group<char, Object, short>, short>, double>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<C>::value)  // 11

    using D = Group<Pack<int, Object, double>, bool, Wrap<char, Pack<char, double, Group<char, Pack<char, long, short>, int, Object>, short>, double>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<D>::value)  // 16

    std::cout << NumTypes<A, B, int, char, C, Object, D>::value << std::endl;  // 38
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` is in fact `std::basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<charT>>`.
And its declaration has default template argument:

```
template <class charT,
          class traits = char_traits<charT>,
          class Alloc = allocator<charT>>
class basic_string;
```

Your recursion is so wrong, And you have infinite loop (when you remove the first parameter from `basic_string<charT, traits, Alloc>`, you got `basic_string<traits, Alloc, allocator<traits>>`).

You may fix that by removing `P` from the equation:

```
template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct NumTypes<P<First, Rest...>> {
    static const int numInFirst = NumTypes<First>::value;
    static const int value = numInFirst + NumTypes<std::tuple<Rest...>>::value;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/467765aa4a33930a)

Comment: that will consider string a grouping type, and count its arguments, which I believe is contrary to the OP's intention.

Comment: Yes, I tested that `std::cout << NumTypes<A, B, int, char, C, Object, D>::value;` gives an incorrect value of 40 instead of the desired value 38 if I replace the 5th type in C with `std::string`.

Comment: @yurikilochek: from OP: *including all types in a nested packs*. I understand that `Pack`, `Group` and `Wrap` are just example.

Comment: Ok, to be clear, I want to view `std::string` as one type.  Not sure how to phrase that then.

Comment: @prestokeys: So you want to *unpack* only your type ?

Comment: @Jarod42.  Actually I want your solution, but view std::string as a single type, but like you explained, that is not the case.  Any way to force std::string (and similar typedefs) to give a value of 1???

Comment: You may add specialization for given type `template <> struct NumTypes<std::string> {static const int value = 1;};`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`, and thus matches specializations of `IsPack` and `NumTypes` you intended for grouping types.

You'll have to specialize either for grouping or template leaf types, whichever'll take less effort in your case:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsPack
    : std::false_type
{};


template <typename...> 
struct NumTypes;

template <typename T, bool is_pack> 
struct NumTypesHelper;

template <typename T>
struct NumTypesHelper<T, false>
    : std::integral_constant<int, 1>
{};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Args>
struct NumTypesHelper<P<Args...>, true>
    : NumTypes<Args...>
{};

template <>
struct NumTypes<>
    : std::integral_constant<int, 0>
{};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct NumTypes<First, Rest...>
    : std::integral_constant<int, NumTypesHelper<First, IsPack<First>::value>::value + NumTypes<Rest...>::value>
{};

template <typename...> struct Pack;
template <typename...> struct Group;
template <typename...> struct Wrap;
struct Object {};

template <typename... Args>
struct IsPack<Pack<Args...>>
    : std::true_type
{};

template <typename... Args>
struct IsPack<Group<Args...>>
    : std::true_type
{};

template <typename... Args>
struct IsPack<Wrap<Args...>>
    : std::true_type
{};

#define show(variable) std::cout << #variable << " = " << variable << std::endl;

int main() {
    using A = Pack<int, Object, long>;
    show (NumTypes<A>::value)  // 3

    using B = Pack<int, bool, Pack<char, double>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<B>::value)  // 5

    using C = Group<int, bool, Wrap<char, Pack<char, long, Group<char, Object, short>, short>, double>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<C>::value)  // 11

    using D = Group<Pack<int, Object, double>, bool, Wrap<char, Pack<char, double, Group<char, Pack<char, long, short>, int, Object>, short>, double>, long>;
    show (NumTypes<D>::value)  // 16
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I haven't decided which answer to accept yet.  Though your solution has the accuracy I want, Jarod42's solution is the type I'm looking for because `Pack`, `Group`, and `Wrap` are not to be viewed in any special way, but at the same time I want `std::string` to give a value of 1 instead of 3.

Comment: @prestokeys you need to either treat `Pack` and others or std::string as and any other such type special by specializing `isPack`.